# Capacitance multiplier

Tags: power-supply, transistors, dc-dc-converter, capacitance, modeling

In my device I'm using a "capacitance multiplier" to filter a DC-DC output voltage. This is my schematic:

[image]

In a Multisim simulation I've achieved the necessary output parameters, but when I had soldered my PCB and measured the output voltage I got huge mismatch.

According to the simulation, when the output load is 10 MΩ (approx. the multimeter's resistance), the voltage is about 4.4 V. When I measure open output I got 3.7 V.

To estimate the loading caracteristics I connected a 10 Ω resistor and got 2.6 V instead of the 3.8 V in the model.

What could cause that mismatch?

Comment: We're missing your input voltage. Note that the circuit is a filter, not a regulator.

Comment: Neither is it an effective capacitance multiplier.

Comment: @Transistor, 5 volts input

Comment: @Andy aka, i'm more RF-engineer than circuit designer, so i dont claim that my solution is absolutely right :)

Comment: @Transistor, of course i understand that it's a filter. In my schematic i use it to minimize noise from DC-DC before LDO to improve noise supresssion, because that voltage goes to RF board.

Comment: *What reasons could cause that mismatch?* What mismatch? The mismatch between **your expectations** and the **actual circuit performance**? With a 10 Mohm load the load current is so small that weird things could happen. My guess is that the transistor model doesn't work well at such a low current. A 10 ohm load means around 100 to 200 mA flowing so series resistances of wires and contacts come into play, did you account for those?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, yeap, exactly expectations. Isn’t it for this that we model before we implement it? I think it could be software "bug" and properly modeling such schemes is litle bit tricky. Wire resistance should not influence because it's wide copper shapes

Comment: Modern LDOs specifically designed for RF applications are pretty good. This circuit would need to be analyzed at AC, and you'd be interested in its AC gain vs. frequency. With the transistors having only 180MHz ft, they won't be doing much active regulation at the frequencies where it matters (>1MHz). This would help maybe in front of a 7805 (it's slow). To a modern LDO this circuit is inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

Zero load current is a problem for many sim programs.  If you calculate the voltage across C30, and through the two base-emitter junctions, you will see that the output never should be above 4 V.

Comment: i think it's most belivable version. I've made this scheme at breadboard and got similiar results. Fortunately, i could rise DC-DC output to compensate "additional' drop, if it does not vaying so much with different load consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need R24, and would have better performance by adding an R (1k) between base and emitter of VT6.

This circuit is basically an emitter follower from the (filtered) signal on C30.

Answer (score 0):

Your capacitor only slows the rate of the voltage change.  The capacitor multiplier does not make your circuit a regulator - it is still a filter.